# Putting the articles as content

Tags: views, blocks

I have a theme with some blocks. I have a problem with adding articles. Right now when I want to add a new article, it appears in each block that exists on the website. How can I put a new article into the specific block on the front page? Each block is about a different topic so it must have different articles. The default layout of the article is good so I want to keep it. I wanted to clone the article but after cloning and giving a new name the layout of the article is not the same as the original version. I will be grateful for your answer.

Comment: I think you should explain what kind of books are you suing and why articles appear on them (are they Views blocks?). Also, you ask at least to things: how to display articles in different blocks, and something about cloning articles that I don't really understand.

Comment: Yep, simply create Views blocks for that. Configure the Views filters to show the node(s) you want and then place the block as usual.